# MS-Windows MakeFIles

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to write makefile for ms-windows application. The idea is very simple. I have to generate the output `.o`, `.exe` files into the build directory. I have written makefile which will compile source directory, but is not able to generate the build directory and compilation process is perfectly working.

Please have a look for the makefile. It looks like i am not able to generate the build directory using mkdir command.

```
CC= gcc
CFLAG= -g -Wall

TARGET_EXEC ?= test.exe

RELEASE=    Release
RELEASE_BIN= bin
RELEASE_CNFG= config
RELEASE_LOG= log
RELEASE_DATA=data

BUILD_DIR ?= build
SRC_DIRS ?= src

#OS dependent cleaning command 
ifdef OS
    RM = rd /s /q
else
   ifeq ($(shell uname), Linux)
        RM = rm -f
   endif
endif

SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIRS)/*.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

INC_DIRS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIRS) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

#find the directory for the include file
#this is best otpion to search curl directory
USR_INC := /usr/include
FILES := 
INCLUDES = -Iinclude

LIBS= -lm

CPPFLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $@  $(LIBS) $(LLFLAGS)

# c source
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
    @echo Compiling $<
# here I am trying to generate the file into the build/src/xxxc.o
    @ $(MKDIR_P) $@      
    $(CC) $(CFLAG) -c $< -o $@ $(INCLUDES)

.PHONY: install

install:
    @ echo "Installing..........."
    @ echo "Creating $(RELEASE) Directory..."
    @ $(MKDIR_P) $(RELEASE)
    @ echo "Creating $(RELEASE)/$(RELEASE_BIN) Directory.."
    @ $(MKDIR_P) $(RELEASE)/$(RELEASE_BIN)
    @ echo "Creating $(RELEASE)/$(RELEASE_CNFG) Directory..."
    @ $(MKDIR_P) $(RELEASE)/$(RELEASE_CNFG)
    @ echo "Creating $(RELEASE)/$(RELEASE_LOG) Directory..."
    @ $(MKDIR_P) $(RELEASE)/$(RELEASE_LOG)
    @ echo "Creating $(RELEASE)/$(RELEASE_DATA) Directory..."
    @ $(MKDIR_P) $(RELEASE)/$(RELEASE_DATA)

    @ echo "Makking Release folder ready.."
    @cp $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC) $(RELEASE)/$(RELEASE_BIN)       
    @ echo "copy certificate file to Release"
    @cp -r cert $(RELEASE)
    @ echo "copy .ini file to Release"
    @cp -r config/*.ini $(RELEASE)/$(RELEASE_CNFG)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) $(BUILD_DIR) $(RELEASE)
    
-include $(DEPS)

MKDIR_P ?= mkdir
```

Comment: No one uses that in Windows. Either use cmake or visual studio.

Comment: Hi, Yes you're right but trying with makefile because later same source code with have to make it for the linux so that's why want to have common build process for both the system

Comment: Make files are used for building a binary executable _for a specific target_. So it doesn't make any sense to have portable make files. Normally you'd just use some IDE claiming to have cross-platform portability and let the IDE worry about the linking.

Comment: "Is not working" is not something we can work with.  Please use the Edit link in your question and show (cut and paste) the command you typed and the output (errors etc.) you got.

Comment: It's absolutely not true that you can't write portable makefiles.  It can take some extra effort for sure but it's clearly do-able.

Comment: The makefile contains much that has nothing to do with the problem. Create a minimal makefile that exhibits the problem.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to run make an any OS. It is perfectly fine to have a portable makefile (however it may or may not be easier to have two), I have never had difficulty having a makefile that will build for multiple targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do understand what your are trying. But please be aware that some differences in platforms and dependencies will force you to create something that is similar to a "configure" and "make" step.

So you will start to generate a custom Makefile in a tool to be invented by you sooner or later :).

It is mentioned in the comments: This has already been done and **cmake** is now "industrial standard"

It works on Windows, Linux, OSX and so on with great toolchain support. Have a look at it!

Example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)

project(HelloWorldCMake)

set(MY_SOURCES
    hello_world.c
)

add_executable(HelloWorldCMake
    ${MY_SOURCES}
    )
```

And hello_world.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world (cmake)");
}
```

If you want to link additional libraries, please research
the CMake command: target_link_libraries
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: Hi. I am trying now cmake option for my project. able to build simple project which is build one .c file. how to do link the windows.h and all file using cmake?

Comment: Please have look at my edited answer.